# How to deal with redundant python.exe when using parallel python(pp)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing

I am using python to conduct a Monte Carlo simuation, which needs 100 times calling of external *.exe for one loop and I have 20 loops. I defined a function responsible for calling external exe program, using `Win32api.ShellExecute` method. For avoiding mutual effect, I copied 100 folders, each of which had *.exe program and they can run without mutual effect.

To speed up calculation efficiency, I tried to use parallel python(pp). My computer has 4 ncpus, and I want to use them to run external *.exe in different folders simultaneously. But I find that with the program running, there will be more and more python.exe hanging-up in task manager, and eventually it will remind me `"OSError [Error 24] Too many open files"` or python kernel died unexpectedly. I don't know if it is necessary to deal with those redundant python.exe, see the image below:

[image: Attached Figure]

My parallel python code is:

```
ppservers=()
    job_server=pp.Server(4,ppservers=ppservers)  #4 is ncpus
    Ne=tuple(range(N))   #N is 100
    jobs=[(i,job_server.submit(runexe,(i,root_directory),(),('win32api',))) for i in Ne]
    for i,job in jobs:
        job()
    while True:
        back_process=os.popen('tasklist |findstr /i ogs.exe').readlines()
        if back_process==[]:
            break
    os.popen('taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq python.exe" /fi "memusage lt 100000"')
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Pool` module from `mutliprocessing`? Might be an easier solution than this...

Comment: I have tried this code, but it did't work and python.exe in task manager changes all the time,but no results presented to me.

Comment: pool=Pool()
    pool.map(runexe,[(i,root_directory) for i in range(N)])  # i, root_directory are parameters for runexe
    pool.close()
    pool.join()